# C# interface for AMS Vending machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access

Has anyone dealt with Vending Machines? I am trying to write a C# interface for AMS vending machine which uses MDB ICP protocol. Although I know a little about Serial Port programming, I am a newbie for writing a hardware interface. I have these questions right now,

a. How do I connect my RS 232 port to this interface, am I suppose to use any other interface or just make use of AMS vending machine's interface? 
b. How do I test the code whatever I write, I have problems connecting to the interface?

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just ask one specific question and show us what you have investigated yourself

Comment: https://www.vendingworld.com/ams-sensit-3-pc-board.php has the picture of the circuit board. All I want to know is how do I connect this circuit board to my computer using RS 232 serial port. This circuit board makes use of MDB ICP protocol, do I need to make any hardware connections before transmitting the data from COM PORT to this PCB.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be too late for you, but there could be other readers as well ;-)
As already stated, you need to have a hardware piece to interface between the the MDB bus and the RS232 interface. 
This hardware piece takes care of the old-school 9 bit protocol and voltage levels (e.g. Current-Loop MDB bus vs. Voltage-Leveled RS232 interface). Your hardware has to pay further attention to meet the MDB timing specs down to 1.5ms; you can't achieve such short timeouts with a standard High-Level OS (e.g. Windows, Linux...). At last, you have to invent an interfacing protocol between RS232 and MDB bus to deal with timing and framing requirements.

You can either engineer that by yourself or buy a solution which takes care of all the mentioned things (e.g. http://blog.abrantix.com/webshop/about-mdb-converter/ - of course, there are other commercial solutions available).

In general, such converters can be addressed by any favored programming language (C#,JAVA,Python...) as long as you can send and receive data from/to a serial and/or USB port.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, fortunately I found this http://www.upstatenetworks.com/pc2asd.htm from Upstate Networks, which can talk to the vending machine, i need to write to the comport, this is connected to the Computer by a USB, that way I just need to pass parameters that needs to be read by this device and it takes care of the rest, I do not have to implement any protocol, later I need to be listening to the port where it writes back what it received from the Vending Machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually get basic communication on a MDB protocol to work using standard RS232 hardware for 8 bit, e.g. common USB-to-RS232 dongles. You can emulate the 9th data bit by switching between MARK and SPACE parity setting.

People obviously have [done this on Linux / Raspberry PI](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38638/true-9-bit-serial-port-data).

But also our Docklight users on Windows access MDP devices via the [temporary parity changes](https://docklight.de/manual/setandreadhandshake.htm#paritychanges) successfully and we have a related [Docklight example for 9 bit](https://docklight.de/exampleFiles/extras/ParitySwitch_9BitProtocols.zip).